# Why is $x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = \frac{d}{dx} (xy)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In my physics textbook it is stated without further explanation that:
$$x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = \frac{d}{dx} (xy)$$
How is this proven?

Comment: Keyword: derivative of a product.

Comment: See [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=y(x)$ is a function of $x$, then this is just the product rule: if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then $fg$ is differentiable and $$\frac{d}{dx}(fg)=\frac{df}{dx}g+f\frac{dg}{dx}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the product rule between $\frac{d}{dx}\left(xy\right)$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(xy\right)=\left(\frac{d}{dx}x\right)y+\left(\frac{d}{dx}y\right)x=y+\frac{dy}{dx}x$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the product rule:

$$\frac{d(fg)}{dx}=f'g+g'f$$
$f=x, g=y$.

Hence $f'=1, g'=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Thus we get $\frac{d(fg)}{dx}=1\cdot y+x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=y+x\frac{dy}{dx}$